# Simple ways to forecast US GDP

Tags: regression, forecasting

Forecasting US GDP sure is hard, even the Fed's FRB/US gets it wrong. I am an undergrad doing a US GDP forecasting project, and was wondering if there were simpler ways to do so and produce decent forecasts?

So far I have identified two simple models for my purpose, one is a basic structural linear OLS model, with regressors like IPI, PCE, Jobless Claims and real GDP as a dependent. It has a decently high MAPE/MAE but is extremely multicollinear and probably spurious.

Another one I have tried is an ARIMA model, but I would prefer a more empirical/structural model. Plus the ARIMA one doesn't actually work that well.

So my question is: are there other methods that are simple enough for me to learn on my own, and still produce decent forecasts? Alternatively, are there any steps I can take to improve my existing models?